# How to make Gnuplot use the "unicode minus" sign for negative numbers

Tags: unicode, gnuplot

Gnuplot uses the hyphen-minus sign (U+002D) when it prints negative numbers (e.g., tick labels). I would like to make Gnuplot use the unicode minus sign (U+2212).

Usually, I have relied on one of the following workarounds:

1. Explicitly set the label of each tick mark using `set xtics (-0.05 "−0.05", ...)`;
2. Export the plot using a LaTeX driver (e.g., `epslatex`) and enclose the number within `$$` (e.g., `set format x "$%.2f$"`).

However, none of the above solution appeals me. Is there any way to make Gnuplot automatically use the correct typographical convention for negative numbers?

Comment: There is no flag or option to use the unicode minus sign with gnuplot.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @Christoph . I've just discovered that Matplotlib has a [flag for this](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/unicode_minus.html). Do you think there's any chance that future versions of Gnuplot will have something similar?

Comment: Yes, if there is a feature request and someone implements this :) Seriously, seeing that for 5.0 a new format specifier `%h` was introduced to produce nicer formatting for the exponential notation, I think the chances for getting this in are quite good.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since version 5.0.5 gnuplot has a `set minussign` command. When this is set, the `gprintf` function, which is also used to set the tics labels, uses typographic minus signs ([U+2212](http://www.decodeunicode.org/u+2212)) instead of a hyphen:

```
set encoding utf8
set minussign
plot x
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the only "solution" that I can find is to plot labels with formatted x axis values using `sprintf`, instead of using xtics `set format x " "`:

```
set format x " "
plot 'data', \
  'data' u 1:(0):(($1 >= 0 ? $1 : sprintf('{\055}%d', -$1))) notitle w labels offset graph 0, -0.55
```

and you would have to find a symbol instead of `{\055}` close to the unicode minus, among the PostScript character codes.

This code assumes that the mean data value is 0, then checks if the x value `$1` is positive `(test ? yes : no)`

Comment: Thanks, Sébastien, your solution has the advantage of not requiring the user to manually re-enter the numbers twice as in my example. I think this is the best solution available, given the limitations of the current Gnuplot version.